# ember-data - store.find('model') always queries the server

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

**Details: ember-data-1.0.0.beta.3 and the default RESTAdapter**

I might have misunderstood how the `store.find()` method works, but, from my understanding, the following code should not query the server if the records I'm asking for are already present in the store:

```
var IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
       return this.store.find('link');
    },
});
```

From the emberjs.com documentation for `DS.Store.find()`:

> The find method will always return a promise that will be resolved with the record. If the record was already in the store, the promise will be resolved immediately. Otherwise, the store will ask the adapter's find method to find the necessary data.

I have another route with the exact same model hook, but when I visit that route, and even though the data is already in the store, the server gets queried. And if I go back to the Index route, it gets queried again. Shouldn't `.find()` handle this?

Comment: Do you have the Ember plugin for Chrome? You can check to see if the data is in the Ember store.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> The find method will always return a promise that will be resolved
>   with the record. If the record was already in the store, the promise
>   will be resolved immediately. Otherwise, the store will ask the
>   adapter's find method to find the necessary data.

This just work when finding by id `this.store.find('link', 1)`. Using `this.store.find('link')` will always perform requests in the server.

You can get the local data using the `all` method `this.store.all('link')`. But in some place of your app, you will need to preload that data using the `find` method. Otherwise `all` will return nothing.

You can use the following to get the desired behavior:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        // preload all data from the server once
        this.store.find('person');
    }
});

App.LinksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {      
      // get the local data without request the server
      return this.store.all('person');
  }
});

App.OtherRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
      // get the local data without request the server
      return this.store.all('person');
  }
});
```

I made a fiddle with this please give a look http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/Az2Uc/

That fiddle uses the jquery mockjax, if you see the browser console the `MOCK GET: /people` is showed just once, this is like a regular xhr request, but it's mocked. Transitioning to `people1` and `people2` won't perform other requests just get the local data.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have a related question though. Maybe you know the answer: 

I have a category model and I load a list of categories in the ApplicationRoute. I have also have a CategoryRoute, but there I have a different problem. `this.store.find('category', params.category_id)` will query the server, but it will use the index action, instead of the show action. However, if I don't load the categories in the ApplicationRoute, it works as expected.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your problem. I recommend you to create another question, so other people can help.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. I added a question with more detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680014/ember-data-store-findmodel-id-force-request-to-server. If you can, please take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I find ember-data's documentation to be very misleading on how the `find()` method uses a cache. Do they mention this anywhere in the docs?

Comment: Thank you so much for this information. This has helped me clear a few doubts!! :)