# ember-data - loading data for a menu - best approach

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a list of categories that are loaded on the application route:

```
ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Em.RSVP.hash({
            collections: this.store.find('collection'),
            categories: this.store.find('category'),
            links: this.store.find('link')
        });
    }
});
```

This triggers the categories index action on the server, as expected. I am doing this because I need to load a list of categories for a menu.

I also have a category route:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('category', { path: '/categories/:category_id' });
});


CategoryRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        this.store.find('category', params.category_id);
    }
});
```

Since there's already a list of categories in the store, there's no request to the server. However, here I want to show more detailed information. I want to send a request to the server's show action.

I am probably not thinking in "the ember way", but it seems to me that I either have to, somehow, force the server request in the route, or create a separate model for the menu categories.

How should one go about this, with ember-data?

**Notes**:
ember.js-1.1.2 and
ember-data-1.0.0.beta.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a separate CategoriesList model. Still, this feels suboptimal.